# What's the meaning of "instead with"?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "instead with"?

I found it in this sentence:

> I had thought **instead with** M. Reimer that the printing of the map (the corrections of which are at the moment on lithography stones) should be deferred for a short term.

<sub>Source: [Understanding Life in the Borderlands: Boundaries in Depth and in Motion](http://books.google.com/books?id=Mnc6pguW220C&pg=PA177), edited by I. William Zartman.</sub>

Comment: There's no meaning of *"instead with"*; it's not a two-word preposition like *"instead of"*. They're two words that just happen to be next to each other. You could equally well say: *"I had instead thought with M. Reimer …"*

Comment: @PeterShor, I'll re edit according to your recommendtion

Comment: It might be easier to read if we shift the word *instead* to the front: *Instead, I had thought with M. Reimer that ...*

Comment: *"I think **with** him that this construction is ungainly, if not actually ungrammatical"*. It would be much better to spell out the relationship more precisely - *"**In line with him**, I think this phrasing sounds better"*.

Answer (score 2):

> I had thought instead with M. Reimer that the printing of the map (the corrections of which are at the moment on lithography stones) should be deferred for a short term.

I would rephrase it like so:

> I had instead thought with M. Reimer that the printing of the map (the corrections of which are at the moment on lithography stones) should be deferred for a short term.

And replace instead with its dictionary definition: ”as an alternative”

The sentence would read:

> I had as an alternative thought with M. Reimer that the printing of the map (the corrections of which are at the moment on lithography stones) should be deferred for a short term.

Edit:

The word **with** here conveys the meaning that I had instead thought together with M. Reimer, that is sharing M. Reimer’s opinion.

Answer (score -2):

It means *rather than that, do it with...*

For [example](http://maximizesocialbusiness.com/guest-posting-backlinks-dead-instead-social-media-12657/):

> Guest Posting for Backlinks is Dead, Do This Instead with Social Media

This means don't guest post for backlinks, instead prefer social media as a powerful tool. I thought of many examples and could fit *instead of* instead of *instead with*. It still conveyed the message. I guess *with* in place of *of* is used to keep the syntax intact.

For instance, if garlic butter is the substitute of potato in some dish to be *eaten with*, you may say - *You can also ask to get garlic butter instead with the potato*. Nice question. +1